# Is there any way to use table and its values as variables simultaneously?

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x

I wrote this code, though it is not showing any errors, I am not able to see any value I entered in the database.

```
import mysql.connector
passdb = mysql.connector.connect(**config)
my_cursor = passdb.cursor()
x = "user1234"
pass_tup = ('twitter', 'user0987', 'useris999')
print(pass_tup)
pass_insert_comm = ("INSERT INTO %x (app_name, username_app, gen_pass) VALUES (%s,%s,%s)")
print((x), pass_tup)
my_cursor.execute(pass_insert_comm, x, pass_tup)
passdb.commit()
print("done")
```

**No error was observed in this code. But it is not entering the values in my database.**

Comment: Please answer as soon as possible. It is really urgent.

Comment: What have you done to debug the problem? https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/326590/843953

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way for me is put a `f` before the string quotes, like

`f"the result is {your_variable}"`

[in code editor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G18xu.png)

unfortunately this just works in >= python3.7. But you can also use `.format`.

`"the result is {your_variable}".format(your_variable=0)`

[in code editor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ag8dr.png)

Your script would be:

```py
x = "user1234"
app_name = 'twitter'
username_app = 'user0987'
gen_pass = 'useris999'
pass_insert_comm = f"INSERT INTO {x} (app_name, username_app, gen_pass) VALUES ({app_name},{username_app},{gen_pass})"
```

[in code editor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WzHre.png)

or

```py
x = "user1234"
app_name = 'twitter'
username_app = 'user0987'
gen_pass = 'useris999'
pass_insert_comm = "INSERT INTO {x} (app_name, username_app, gen_pass) VALUES ({app_name},{username_app},{gen_pass})".format(
    x=x, app_name=app_name, username_app=username_app, gen_pass=gen_pass
)
```

[in code editor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I40kd.png)